# Laravel trying to store multi-data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to store multi-data to my pivot table. I have `CategoryUser` table with `category_id` and `user_id.`

**Store function**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->userId as $key => $userId) {
        $data = new CategoryUser();
        $data->user_id = $userId;
        $data->category_id = $request->categoryId[$key];
        $data->save();
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

In my Blade file i have `name="categoryId[]"` and `name="userId[]"`.
However,  it stores only one `category_id`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes it's fillable like category_id

Comment: it's stores only one record user_id=1 category_id=1 but it must store user_id=1 category_id=1 / user_id=1 category_id=2 / user_id=1 category_id=3

Comment: It's always will be one user_id and multi category_ids

Comment: if it is only 1 user id it shouldn't be an array, it should just be `userId` as the name, then you would just loop through the `categoryId` ... is there any reason you are not using an Eloquent Belongs To Many relationship here?

Comment: i'm new in this so i really don't know so much to do that i'm using belongsToMany with pivot table

Answer (score 0):

For 1 user ID case, loop through category ID array first.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->categoryId as $key => $categoryID) {
        $data = new CategoryUser();
        $data->user_id = $request->userId[0];
        $data->category_id = $categoryID[$key];
        $data->save();
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer now i'm getting ' Uninitialized string offset 1 ' error

Comment: Can you use dd  method on both $categoryId and $userId  and add here?

Comment: on $categoryID  showing 1  and i'm don't having $userId variable so i can't do dd.  when i save it it's errors but it's saving in database but it's saving only category_id=1 user_id=1 it's not saving other categories